# simple groovy test with variables in the where section

Tags: groovy, automated-tests

Sorry for the noob question but just starting to learn groovy coming from a java testing background.

I have the below code which works if I set the data in the where section

```
def "Groovy Test"() {
        given:
        def primerEndpoint = new RESTClient( 'http://localhost:8080/' )
        primerEndpoint.headers['username'] = "username"
        when:
        def resp = primerEndpoint.get( path: 'testme/')
        then:
        def assertvalue1 = "1"
        def assertvalue2 = "2"  
        //println resp.data[0]
        assert resp.data[0] == value1
        where:
        value1 | value2
        "1" | "2"
    }
```

Now I would love to parameterize the hardcoded "1" and "2" values so i tried the below which does not work

```
def "Groovy Test"() {
        given:
        def primerEndpoint = new RESTClient( 'http://localhost:8080/' )
        primerEndpoint.headers['username'] = "username"
        when:
        def resp = primerEndpoint.get( path: 'testme/')
        then:
        def assertvalue1 = "1"
        def assertvalue2 = "2"
        //println resp.data[0]
        assert resp.data[0] == value1
        where:
        value1 | value2
        assertvalue1 | assertvalue2
    }
```

The error I get is " No such property: assertvalue1 for class"
I am not sure if i can set assertvalue1 and 2 in the then: section or even if this is possible or not. I have searched around but have not found much so any help would be awesome.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please see below code for the complete answer

```
@Shared def assertvalue1 = "1"
@Shared def assertvalue2 = "2"

def "Groovy Test"() {
        given:
        def primerEndpoint = new RESTClient( 'http://localhost:8080/' )
        primerEndpoint.headers['username'] = "username"
        when:
        def resp = primerEndpoint.get( path: 'testme/')
        then:
        //println resp.data[0]
        assert resp.data[0] == value1

        where:
        value1 | value2
        assertvalue1 | assertvalue2
    }
```